How to prove that $\left|G_1/H\right| = \left|G_2/H\right|$ implies $\left|G_1\right| = \left|G_2\right|$ using category theory?
Exercise 8.1 of Paolo Aluffi's Algebra: Chapter 0 (on p. 105), says:

8.1. If a group $H$ may be realized as a subgroup of two groups $G_1$ and $G_2$ and if $$\frac{G_1}{H}\cong\frac{G_2}{H},$$ does it follow that $G_1\cong G_2$?  Give a proof or a counterexample.

Since the question does not say that $H$ is normal in both $G_1$ and $G_2$, I have to assume that $G_1/H$ and $G_2/H$ refer to sets (rather than groups) of (left-)cosets of $H$, and thus that the isomorphisms in the question are isomorphisms in $\textbf{Set}$, not in $\textbf{Grp}$.
If this interpretation is correct, then the question boils down to proving (or disproving) that $$\left|\frac{G_1}{H}\right| = \left|\frac{G_2}{H}\right| \;\; \Rightarrow \;\; \left|G_1\right| = \left|G_2\right|.$$
When the $G_i$ are finite, then the desired implication follows immediately from Lagrange's theorem: $$\left|G_1\right|=\left[G_1:H\right] \centerdot \left|H\right|=\left|\frac{G_1}{H}\right| \centerdot \left|H\right|=\left|\frac{G_2}{H}\right| \centerdot \left|H\right|=\left[G_2:H\right] \centerdot \left|H\right|=\left|G_2\right|.$$
The version of Lagrange's theorem I know, however, applies only to finite groups.
Therefore, the problem is to prove the desired assertion in the absence of the finiteness assumption.
Now, for each $i\in\{1, 2\}$, $G_i$ is the disjoint union of a family of sets $G_i/H$.  These families $G_i/H$ are set-isomorphic to each other, and their elements are all set-isomorphic to $H$.
Given all this, it seems to me intuitively obvious that $G_1$ and $G_2$ must be set-isomorphic.  My difficulty lies in formalizing this intuition.  In particular, I would like to do this using category theory.
Here's the best I can do.
Let $\varphi$ be the assumed set-isomorphism from $G_1/H$ to $G_2/H$.  For each left-coset $gH \in G_1/H$, both $gH$ and $\varphi(gH)$ are set-isomorphic to $H$, and therefore, they are set-isomorphic to each other.  In other words, for each $gH \in G_1/H$ there exists a set isomorphism $\psi_{gH}:gH \to \varphi(gH)$.  Finally, let $\pi_1$ be the canonical projection $G_1 \twoheadrightarrow G_1/H$.
Now we can describe the desired isomorphims $G_1 \to G_2$ as the mapping $\rho:G_1\to G_2$ given by $$\rho:g \mapsto \psi_{\pi_1(g)}(g).$$
As proofs go, this one seems to me pretty close to hand-waving.  (For example, it does not formally take into account the fact that the $G_i$ are disjoint unions of the elements of the corresponding $G_i/H$, not to mention the fact that it does not prove that $\rho$ is a bijection.)  It is certainly devoid of any category theory at all.

It is certainly weird of Aluffi not to specify either that we're looking at normal subgroups or at isomorphisms of sets.

Yeah, that sent me for a loop...  FWIW, the errata page at https://www.math.fsu.edu/~aluffi/algebraerrata.2016/Errata.html is also silent on the matter.

$|G| = |G/H|\cdot |H|$, this works for any group, finite or infinite. The reason people specify that $G$ is finite is so that they can make sense of equality $|G/H| = |G|/|H|$, but we don't need that here.

If you are looking for a set bijection, choose by the Axiom of Choice a section $s : G/H \to G$ of the canonical projection $p : G \to G/H$. That is to say, $s(g) H = gH$ for all $g\in G$, so that $s(g) ^{-1} g \in H$. Then the map $f : G \to H \times G/H$ given by
$$f(g) = (s(g)^{-1} g, gH) $$
is a bijection of sets.

Could you add an explicit isomorphism between $G$ and $H\times G/H$?

Let $G_1 = \mathbb{Z} $ be the additive abelian group of integers. Let $H = 2\mathbb{Z} \le G_1$ be the subgroup of even integers. Then $G_1/H = \mathbb{Z} /2\mathbb{Z}$ is the cyclic group of order 2. We can regard $H$ as a subgroup of $G_2 := H \oplus G_1/H = 2\mathbb{Z} \oplus  \mathbb{Z} /2\mathbb{Z}$. Then, by design,
$$G_2/H \cong G_1/H, $$
as (abelian) groups.
But $G_2$ is not isomorphic to $G_1$, since for instance $G_2$ has an element of order 2 (namely $(0, 1 + 2\mathbb{Z}$), but every nonidentity element of $G_1$ has infinite order.

This doesn't answer the question as asked.  They're looking for a bijection, not an isomorphism.
